# Lisp - Print out () instead of nil for empty list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a Lisp program that's going through nested list and deleting elements that match the element passed through to the function. My issue is, if everything in one of the nested list is deleted, I need to print out () instead of NIL.

```
(defun del (x l &optional l0)
  (cond ((null l) (reverse l0))
    ((if (atom x) (eq x (car l)) (remove (car l) x)) (del x (cdr l) l0))
    (T (del x (cdr l) (cons (if (not (atom (car l))) 
                                    (del x (car l)) 
                                    (car l))
                                 l0)))))

(defun _delete(a l)
(format t "~a~%" (del a l)))

(_delete 'nest '(nest (second nest level) (third (nest) level)))
```

This returns

```
((SECOND LEVEL (THIRD NIL LEVEL))
```

And I need

```
((SECOND LEVEL (THIRD () LEVEL))
```

I've tried using the ~:S format but that apparently doesn't work with composite structures. I've also tried the substitute function to replace NIL, also with no results.

Comment: May I ask why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Two possible solutions:

I. You can use the format directives `~:A` or `~:S`

```
(format t "~:a" '()) => ()
```

However, this directive works only on the top level elements of a list, i.e.

```
(format t "~:a" '(a b () c))
```

will not print `(A B () C)`

but `(A B NIL C)`

So you need to loop through the list applying the `~:A` to each element recursively if it is a cons.

```
(defun print-parentheses (l)
  (cond ((consp l) (format t "(")
              (do ((x l (cdr x)))
                  ((null x) (format t ")" ))
                (print-parentheses (car x))
                (when (cdr x) (format t " "))))
        (t (format t "~:a" l)) ))


(print-parentheses '(a b (c () d))) => (A B (C () D))
```

II. Create a print-dispatch function for empty lists and add it to the pretty print dispatch table:

```
(defun print-null (stream obj)
  (format stream "()") )

(set-pprint-dispatch 'null #'print-null)

(print '(a () b)) => (A () B)
```

The latter is simpler, but it affects all the environment, which might not be what you want.

Comment: For the pprint dispatch to work, `*print-pretty*` needs to be T.

Answer (score 3):

We can write an `:around` method for `print-object`, for the case when the object to be printed is `NIL`.

```
(defvar *PRINT-NIL-AS-PARENS* nil
  "When T, NIL will print as ().")

(defmethod print-object :around ((object (eql nil)) stream)
  (if *print-nil-as-parens*
      (write-string "()" stream)
    (call-next-method)))

(defun write-with-nil-as-parens (list)
  (let ((*print-nil-as-parens* t))
    (write list)))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 73 > (write-with-nil-as-parens '(a b c nil (()) (nil)))
(A B C () (()) (()))                  ; <- printed
(A B C NIL (NIL) (NIL))               ; <- return value
```

Comment: I tend to specialize on class `null` in such cases. I suppose it is just a style difference, but is there any technical reason for specializing on `(eql nil)`? portability?

Comment: @coredump: just style. Haven't even compared performance. I tend to see NIL as an object, not so much as a instance of a class, which stands in for a type.

Comment: Thanks, I understand.

Comment: See clause 19 of http://l1sp.org/cl/11.1.2.1.2 - the consequences of defining this method are undefined. I think pprint-dispatch is the way to go.

Comment: @Xach: In this case I would not care too much about writing a method, though it is a hack.  The only safety check I would add, to see if the method already exists...
The pprint-dispatch is great, but then you are pretty printing the list, which may or may not what one want. To get rid of the pretty printing (with an altered dispatch table) and still use the pprint-dispatch is difficult. I couldn't find how to create an empty dispatch table, for example.

Answer (score 0):

> *I've also tried the substitute function to replace NIL, also with no results.*

None of the standard substitution functions will work. `substitute` is a sequence processing function: it will not recurse into the tree structure.

The `sublis` and `subst` functions will process the tree structure, but they treat the `car` and `cdr` fields of conses equally: if we replace `nil` throughout a tree structure with `:whatever`, that applies to all of the terminating atoms, so that `(a nil b)` becomes `(a :whatever b . :whatever)`.

We must make our out function which is like `subst`, but only affects `car`-s:

```
(defun subcar (old new nested-list)
  (cond
    ((eq nested-list old) new)
    ((atom nested-list) nested-list)
    (t (mapcar (lambda (atom-or-sublist)
                 (subcar old new atom-or-sublist))
               nested-list))))
```

With this, we can replace `nil`-s with the character string `"()"`:

```
[1]> (subcar nil "()" '(a b c nil (e nil f (g nil)) nil))
(A B C "()" (E "()" F (G "()")) "()")
```

If we pretty-print that, the character strings just print as the data rather than as machine-readable string literals:

```
[2]> (format t "~a~%" *)  ;; * in the REPL refers to result of previous evaluation
(A B C () (E () F (G ())) ())
```

---

I hope you understand that `nil` and `()` mean exactly the same thing; they are the same object:

```
[3]> (eq nil ())
T
```

The only way the symbol *token* `nil` can denote an object other than `()` is if we we are in a package which hasn't imported the `nil` symbol from the `common-lisp` package (and `nil` is interned as a local symbol in that package, completely unrelated to `cl:nil`):

```
[1]> (defpackage "FOO" (:use))
#<PACKAGE FOO>
[2]> (in-package "FOO")
#<PACKAGE FOO>
```

Sanity test: from within package `foo` check that `cl:nil` is the same as the `()` object. We have to refer to the `eq` function as `cl:eq` because package `foo` doesn't import anything from `cl`:

```
FOO[3]> (cl:eq cl:nil ())
COMMON-LISP:T
```

Now let's see if `nil` in this package is `()`:

```
FOO[4]> (cl:eq nil ())

*** - SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-PRINT: variable NIL has no value
```

OOPS! This is not the standard `nil` anymore; it doesn't have special the behavior that it evaluates to itself. We must quote it:

```
FOO[6]> (cl:eq 'nil ())
COMMON-LISP:NIL
```

Nope, not the `()` object. Note how the return values of the `cl:eq` function are printed as `COMMON-LISP:NIL` or `COMMON-LISP:T`. Symbols are printed without a package prefix only if they are present in the current package.