# How to return empty list as an element of a list

Tags: list, recursion, lisp, common-lisp

What I am trying to do here is to delete each element that has the same depth as I want. So, for example this test

```
(del-sublist '(a b c (d) ((e) a)) 2)
```

should return:

```
(A B C (D) (A))
```

Here is my code.

```
(defun del-sublist (l n)
  (if (null l) '()
      (let ((el (car l)))   
        (if (= n 0) nil  
            (cond  
              ((atom el)
                 (remove nil (cons el
                       (del-sublist (cdr l) n)))) 
              ((listp el)
                 (remove nil (cons '()
                                   (cons (del-sublist el (- n 1))
                                         (del-sublist (cdr l) n))))))))))
```

This code doesn't work for this kinda test:

```
(del-sublist '(a b c (d (()) e) ((e) a)) 3)
```

It returns:

```
(A B C (D E) ((E) A))
```

When it's supposed to return this:

```
(A B C (D () E) ((E) A))
```

This algorithm should delete all the elements of the same depth(or greater) but leave the rest. I just don't know how to return an empty list.

The whole idea of the algorithm is that when you go inside the bracket your depth level increases and when you are on the right level you remove everything in there until you go outside this bracket and your depth level decreases back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in Lisp `()` and `NIL` are exactly the same object.

Maybe something like this:

```
(defun del-sublist (l n)
  (cond ((null l)
         ())
        ((and (atom l) (zerop n))
         l)
        ((zerop n)
          nil)
        (t
         (let ((el (first l)))
           (cond ((null el)
                  (del-sublist (rest l) n))
                 ((atom el)
                  (cons el (del-sublist (rest l) n)))
                 (t
                  (cons (del-sublist el (- n 1))
                        (del-sublist (rest l) n))))))))
```

Empty list:

```
CL-USER 107 > (del-sublist '() 0)
NIL
```

One level:

```
CL-USER 108 > (del-sublist '(a b c) 0)
NIL

CL-USER 109 > (del-sublist '(a b c) 1)
(A B C)
```

Two levels:

```
CL-USER 110 > (del-sublist '(a (b) c) 0)
NIL

CL-USER 111 > (del-sublist '(a (b) c) 1)
(A NIL C)

CL-USER 112 > (del-sublist '(a (b) c) 2)
(A (B) C)
```

Three levels:

```
CL-USER 113 > (del-sublist '(a (b (d) e) c) 0)
NIL

CL-USER 114 > (del-sublist '(a (b (d) e) c) 1)
(A NIL C)

CL-USER 115 > (del-sublist '(a (b (d) e) c) 2)
(A (B NIL E) C)

CL-USER 116 > (del-sublist '(a (b (d) e) c) 3)
(A (B (D) E) C)

CL-USER 117 > (del-sublist '(a (b (d) (f) e) c) 3)
(A (B (D) (F) E) C)

CL-USER 118 > (del-sublist '(a (b (d) (f) e) c) 2)
(A (B NIL NIL E) C)
```

Comment: It returns `NIL` instead of each element that you don't need. There should be nothing if you don't need that atom. If you have an empty list (empty brackets) inside your result and this list is on the right depth, you should just leave it the way it is. look at my example above.

Comment: @AntonKaravaev: NIL and () are the same in Lisp.

Comment: i know that but i need to diplay `()` on the screen and not `NIL`

Comment: @AntonKaravaev: then you need to configure the printer. For Lisp it makes zero difference if your input or output either () or NIL. It's the same.

Comment: @AntonKaravaev: for configuring the printer see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457915/lisp-print-out-instead-of-nil-for-empty-list

Comment: i guess im just gonna leave `NIL`s instead of `()`

Comment: this should result                                                                                      `(del-sublist '(c a (a ((b) a a (b)) a) (a d (a a) (b a a (b a a (b) a z) a h a a (b) a) a)) 2)`                                                                                                      into this `(c a (a a) (a d a))`

Comment: @AntonKaravaev: then you only need to remove nils in the last clause...

Comment: @AntonKaravaev: but it then violates the example you gave in your question... check your example.

Comment: a list that has a `NIL` inside is not a `NIL` it is an atom that has nothing inside. so in this case when we have `(NIL)` left, you shouldn't print just `NIL` we should print `()`

Comment: @AntonKaravaev: () and NIL are the absolute same thing, Lisp does not know a difference and it cannot do so. The printer is a generic piece of software, which by default will only print one version. Don't think about what it prints, think about what the function returns.

Comment: `(A B C (D () E) ((E) A))` is printed as -> `(A B C (D NIL E) ((E) A))` -> and both are the same.

Comment: yes, `()` and `NIL` is the same thing, but `NIL` and `(NIL)` is not.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should do this recursively.  As long as `n` is bigger than 1 (or maybe 0?), just keep every atom and recurse with `(1- n)` into every list.  When `n` is 1 (or maybe 0?), return the empty list.

I also do not see how your examples could be consistent if the second doesn't return `(A B C (D () E) (() A))`.